# How to use powershell to reorder CSV columns?

Tags: powershell, csv

Input file:

```
column1;column2;column3
data1a;data2a;data3a
data1b;data2b;data3b
```

Goal: An output file with reordered columns like this:

```
column1;column3;column2
...
```

**Question:** *What is a good way of using powershell to solve this problem?*

I am aware of the existence of CSV related cmdlets, but these have limitations. Note that the order of records does not need to be changed, so loading the entire input/output file in memory should not be needed.

Comment: What is the question exactly? How to reorder columns or how to make it working in the case of millions of records? (I have some experience, the straightforward solution does not work well).

Comment: That is true, I was simply addressing the reordering of columns if file size is an issue, then the solution will certainly become considerably more involved.

Comment: For millions of rows, I'd load the file into a database and export rows in required order. MSSQL has pretty sophisticated import/export tools, but about any database will do.

Comment: Measure, always.. The less time you spend on creating your solution, the more time you can enjoy your life ;) (see my answer why)

Answer (score 25):

Here is the solution suitable for millions of records (assuming that your data do not have embedded ';')

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText('data1.csv')
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter 'data2.csv'
for(;;) {
    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    if ($null -eq $line) {
        break
    }
    $data = $line.Split(";")
    $writer.WriteLine('{0};{1};{2}', $data[0], $data[2], $data[1])
}
$reader.Close()
$writer.Close()
```

Comment: That looks like a better solution.

Comment: Best solution to the actual OP +1

Comment: +1: Wow. 3 minutes, 56 seconds with the same 10,000,000 rows I used to test mine. Very nice, indeed. I'm now curious what my bottleneck is. Maybe the `TextFieldParser`.

Comment: It can be even faster a little bit (~8%) if we replace 2 lines `$data = ... $writer.WriteLine ...` with one slightly more cryptic `$writer.WriteLine('{0};{2};{1}', $line.Split(";"))`

Comment: I'd actually say that's more readable. It puts the indexes closer together, making the displacement easier to grasp.

Comment: I agree that this is a fast solution for this set of data. However, it might not handle quoted fields where the field separator appears in the field data.

Comment: This doesn't work with Text Qualifiers. If either the field separator or a CRLF appears in the qualified text then the solution breaks.

Answer (score 22):

```
Import-CSV C:\Path\To\Original.csv | Select-Object Column1, Column3, Column2 | Export-CSV C:\Path\To\Newfile.csv
```

Comment: See my question to the author.

Comment: See my response to your question to the author :)

Comment: And just to be clear, I realize that my answer is really only half of the full answer to the OP. I plan to leave it here though so that anyone that wanders onto this topic later and is dealing with smaller files will have a more simple answer to their issue.

Comment: imho good answer (because google sees mainly the title), will +1 this one and the others as well :)

Comment: Fortunately, `Import-CSV` does not read the entire file into memory when piped, and this solution is faster than my Powershell version (32 minutes, 44 seconds). `Export-CSV` probably needs to be told not to enclose every field in quotes, though. :)

Comment: Fantastic... each day I get more impressed about how StackOverflow helps us get the job done in a matter of minutes. This PowerShell solution is excellent. I got here while trying to do this using Sublime Text 2 but couldn't find a way. http://www.sublimetext.com

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**: Benchmarking info below.

I would not use the Powershell csv-related cmdlets. I would use either `System.IO.StreamReader` or `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` for reading in the file line-by-line to avoid loading the entire thing in memory, and I would use `System.IO.StreamWriter` to write it back out. The `TextFieldParser` internally uses a `StreamReader`, but handles parsing delimited fields so you don't have to, making it very useful if the CSV format is not straightforward (e.g., has delimiter characters in quoted fields).

I would also not do this in Powershell at all, but rather in a .NET application, as it will be much faster than a Powershell script even if they use the same objects.

Here's C# for a simple version, assuming no quoted fields and ASCII encoding:

```
static void Main(){
    string source = @"D:\test.csv";
    string dest = @"D:\test2.csv";

    using ( var reader = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser( source, Encoding.ASCII ) ) {
        using ( var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter( dest, false, Encoding.ASCII ) ) {
            reader.SetDelimiters( ";" );
            while ( !reader.EndOfData ) {
                var fields = reader.ReadFields();
                swap(fields, 1, 2);
                writer.WriteLine( string.Join( ";", fields ) );
            }
        }
    }
}

static void swap( string[] arr, int a, int b ) {
    string t = arr[ a ];
    arr[ a ] = arr[ b ];
    arr[ b ] = t;
}
```

Here's the Powershell version:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.VisualBasic")

$source = 'D:\test.csv'
$dest = 'D:\test2.csv'

$reader = new-object Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser $source
$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $dest

function swap($f,$a,$b){ $t = $f[$a]; $f[$a] = $f[$b]; $f[$b] = $t}

$reader.SetDelimiters(';')
while ( !$reader.EndOfData ) {
    $fields = $reader.ReadFields()
    swap $fields 1 2
    $writer.WriteLine([string]::join(';', $fields))
}

$reader.close()
$writer.close()
```

I benchmarked both of these against a 3-column csv file with 10,000,000 rows. The C# version took 171.132 seconds (just under 3 minutes). The Powershell version took 2,364.995 seconds (39 minutes, 25 seconds).

**Edit**: Why mine take so darn long.

The swap function is a huge bottleneck in my Powershell version. Replacing it with `'{0};{1};{2}'`-style output like Roman Kuzmin's answer cut it down to less than 9 minutes. Replacing `TextFieldParser` more than halved the remaining to under 4 minutes.

However, a .NET console app version of Roman Kuzmin's answer took 20 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

It's great that people came with their solutions based on pure .NET. However, I would fight for the simplicity, if possible. That's why I upvoted all of you ;)

Why? I tried to generate 1.000.000 records and store it in CSV and then reorder the columns.
Generating the csv was in my case much more demanding then the reordering. Look at the results.

It took only 1,8 minute to reorder the columns. For me it's pretty decent result. *Is it ok for me? -> Yes, I don't need to try to find out quicker solution, it's good enough -> saved my time for some other interesting stuff* ;)

```
# generate some csv; objects have several properties
measure-command { 
    1..1mb | 
    % { 
        $date = get-date
        New-Object PsObject -Property @{
            Column1=$date
            Column2=$_
            Column3=$date.Ticks/$_ 
            Hour = $date.Hour
            Minute = $date.Minute
            Second = $date.Second
            ReadableTime = $date.ToLongTimeString()
            ReadableDate = $date.ToLongDateString()
        }} | 
    Export-Csv d:\temp\exported.csv 
}

TotalMinutes      : 6,100025295

# reorder the columns
measure-command { 
    Import-Csv d:\temp\exported.csv | 
        Select ReadableTime, ReadableDate, Hour, Minute, Second, Column1, Column2, Column3 | 
        Export-Csv d:\temp\exported2.csv 
}

TotalMinutes      : 2,33151559833333
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
$new_csv = new-object system.collections.ArrayList
get-content mycsv.csv |% {
$new_csv.add((($_ -split ";")[0,2,1]) -join ";") > $nul
}
$new_csv | out-file myreordered.csv
```

Comment: It will take hours with a million of records due to `+=` approach. Try :)

Comment: And that's assuming it doesn't run out of memory, as `get-content` will read the entire thing into memory first.

Comment: So will import-csv.  The difference is that import-csv will be storing it in memory as [object[]], and this will store it as [string[]]. The [string[]] should have substantially less memory requirements.

Comment: Roman is right about the += being a serious performance issue. Changing to arraylist type and using the .add method instead seems to be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Some very overly complicated answers here.

```
$csv = @("row1","row2")

function arrayToCSV($arr) {
    function ql { $args }
    $csv_header_old = (ql col1, col2, col3)
    $csv_header_new = (ql col1, col3, col2)

    $new = $arr
        | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $csv_header_old
        | Select-Object -Property $csv_header_new
        | ForEach-Object {$_.col2 = "2"; $_.col3 = "3"; $_}  # optional!
        | ConvertTo-Csv -QuoteFields ''
    return $new
}

arrayToCSV($csv)

# <output>
# col1,col3,col2
# row1,3,2
# row2,3,2
```

---

This *magic* pipe does a few things.

1. It creates a CSV from a *naked* list `@()`
2. It creates an object
3. It adds 2 new columns to the object
4. It rearranges the new columns
5. It changes the content of the new columns
6. It constructs a new CSV

**Q:** *So where's the magic?*
**A:** (a) The *only-arg*s `ql()` function avoid's any verbose quotes, while expanding the (non-*splattable*) function arguments. (b) This is a pipe-only solution that conserve memory and possibly faster.

Enjoy! ✨