# How to process large CSV file in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to find the number of rows in a csv file that have above a certain value. The code I have goes something like

```
$T6=Import-Csv $file | Where-Object {$_."Value" -ge 0.6 } | Measure-Object
```

This works well for smaller files but for large csv files(1 GB or more) it will run forever. Is there any better way to parse csv files like this in powershell?

Comment: please edit your post to quantify 'painfully slow' and 'large CSV file'. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Import-Csv is the official cmdlet for this. One comment though, everything imported is a string, so you better cast the Value property to the correct type. For instance:

```
$T6 = Import-Csv $file | Where-Object { [float]$_.Value -ge 0.6 } | Measure-Object
```

Comment: Casting the Value will increase performance dramatically. Just tested this. Literally increase performance 1000-fold.

Comment: with your import-csv and your cast, it's equivalent to ReadAllText solution on big files?

Answer (score 2):

For speed when processing large files consider using a streamreader, Roman's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6387587/847990) demonstrates usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get rid of `Import-Csv`:

```
$values = ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\pst\New Microsoft Office Excel Worksheet.csv')).Split(";") | where {$_ -ne ""}

$items = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[decimal]" 

foreach($value in $values)
{
    [decimal]$out = New-Object decimal
    if ([System.Decimal]::TryParse($value, [ref] $out))
      {
         if ($out -ge 10){$items.Add($out)}
      } 
   }
$items | Measure-Object
```