# How can I specify the column ordering when exporting to CSV in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv, formatting, export-to-csv

I'm writing a script in PowerShell that exports all security groups and their members from Active Directory. Now I want to format the output of the CSV file.

The code:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=SERVICES,DC=XXXXXX,DC=XXXXX" 

$Table = @()

$Record = @{
    "Group Name" = ""
    "Name" = ""
    "Username" = ""
}

Foreach($G In $Groups)
{
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $G -recursive | select name,samaccountname
    Foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) 
    {
        $Record."Group Name" = $G.Name
        $Record."Name" = $Member.name
        $Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
        $Table += $objrecord
    }
}

$Table | export-csv "C:\temp\SecurityGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The result:

```
"Username","Name","Group Name"
"aman","Ani Manoukian","Commercial"
"adan","Aurelia Danneels","Commercial"
"kdeb","Kathleen De Backer","Commercial"
"TVGR","Thijs Van Grimbergen","Commercial"
"SVDE","Sofie Van den Eynde","Commercial"
```

**Now I want the output formatted in this order:**

`"Group Name","Name","Username"`

Instead of:
`"Username","Name","Group Name"`

Comment: For a more complete and flexible solution, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74758686/1147688) answer, taking a list and doing some additional CSV magic.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This should work...

```
$Table |
  Select-Object "Group Name", "Name", "Username" |
  Export-Csv "C:\temp\SecurityGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This answer also works when you don't control creation of the collection (or don't want to)

Answer (score 55):

[gvee's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42090964/45375) is a **pragmatic** solution that ensures that the columns appear in the desired order, because the order in which you pass property names to `Select-Object` is the order in which the properties are added to the resulting `[pscustomobject]` instances.

It is, however, **inefficient**, because **the desired column order can be ensured at the time `$Record` is *defined***, without needing an additional pipeline stage that effectively duplicates the result objects:

Define `$Record` as an ***ordered* hashtable** as follows (requires **PSv3+**; optional quoting omitted; use of single quotes):

```bash
$Record = [ordered] @{
    'Group Name' = ''
    Name = ''
    Username = ''
}
```

This guarantees that the `[pscustomobject]` instances later created by the `New-Object PSObject -property $Record` calls contain properties in the same order as the keys were defined in `$Record`.

Two asides:

- `New-Object PSObject -property $Record` could be simplified to `[pscustomobject] $Record` (see below)
- Building up a large array incrementally is more efficiently handled with a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instance to which you add elements with `.Add()` rather than using PowerShell's built-in arrays with `+=`, which creates a copy of the array every time. Even better is to let PowerShell create the array for you, simply by capturing the output from your `foreach` loop in a variable (`$Table = foreach ...` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642878/45375))

---

#### Supplemental information:

The source of the problem is that **regular hashtables (`[hashtable]` instances) enumerate their keys in an effectively *unpredictable* order** (the order is an implementation detail and *not guaranteed*), and when you create a `[pscustomobject]` from a hashtable, that unpredictable key ordering is reflected in the ordering of the resulting object's properties.

By contrast, in **PSv3+** you can **create an *ordered* hashtable** by placing the **`[ordered]` keyword** before a hashtable literal, which results in a **`[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`** instance whose **keys are ordered based on the order in which they were *added***.
Creating a `[pscustomobject]` instance from an ordered hashtable then preserves that key ordering in the resulting object's properties.

Note that PowerShell v3+ offers a **convenient shortcut for creating a `[pscustomobject]` instance from a hashtable using a *cast***; e.g.:

```bash
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3 } # key order is PRESERVED

a b c
- - -
1 2 3
```

Note how the key-definition order *was* preserved, even though `[ordered]` was not specified.
In other words: **When you cast a hashtable literal *directly* to `[pscustomobject]`, `[ordered]` is *implied***, so the above is equivalent to:

```bash
[pscustomobject] [ordered] @{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3 }  # [ordered] is optional
```

**Caveat**: This implicit ordering *only* applies when a hashtable *literal* is *directly* cast to `[pscustomboject]`, so the key/property order is *not* preserved in the following variations:

```bash
New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3 } # !! order NOT preserved

$ht = @{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3 }; [pscustomobject] $ht # !! order NOT preserved

[pscustomobject] (@{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3 }) # !! order NOT preserved, due to (...)
```

Therefore, when not casting a hashtable literal *directly* to `[pscustomobject]`, define it with `[ordered]` explicitly.