# Parsing a file to create an array of lines

Tags: powershell

This seems so incredibly simple but I am missing something. I just need to add an array to array[0], array[1], etc.
I am taking a vcard file and trying to read all the lines of one vcard and put them in an array and then place that array in an array so array[0] will be vcard 1, array[1] will be the next, etc.

```
$c = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Contacts_Backup.vcf
$counter=0
$contact=@()
$allcontacts=@()

Foreach ($line in $c){
    $contact += $line
    if ($line -eq 'END:VCARD'){
        $allcontacts[$counter++] = $contact
        $contact=@()
        }
}
```

Result:
Unable to index into an object of type System.String.

Comment: you usually need to prefix the sub-array with a comma to add it _as an array_ to another array. ///// however, i suspect you would be better off making a custom object of the VCF content and adding _that_ to your master collection.

Comment: Could you post the whole error please. So i can figure out what line you are getting the error on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- **You cannot "grow" an array by assigning to a *nonexistent index***; if you start with `@()` - an empty array - you **must use `+=`** to "append" elements (arrays are fixed-size collections, so what really happens is that **a *new* array must be allocated every time** that contains the old elements followed by the new one).
- **Using `+=` is therefore inefficient in loops**, and there are two **alternatives**:

  - Use a .NET extensible list type to build an array-like collection more efficiently.
  - Preferably - because it is both more convenient and faster - **let *PowerShell* create the array for you, simply by capturing the output from a `foreach` loop in a variable**
    (`$array = @(foreach (...) { ... })`)

Details below.

---

Your code indeed has a problem, though the symptom it would produce differs from what your question currently states; using a simplified example:

```
PS> $allcontacts=@(); $allcontacts[0] = 'one', 'two'
Index was outside the bounds of the array.  # ERROR
...
```

That is, `@()` creates an *empty* array, which you cannot implicitly "extend" by accessing a non-existent *index*.

Using `+=`, as you do with your `$contacts` array, does work:

```
$allcontacts=@(); $allcontacts += , ('one', 'two')
```

Note the use of array-construction operator `,` to ensure that the RHS operand is added *as a whole* as a *single* new element; without it, *multiple* elements would be added, one for each element.

However, while "extending" an array with `+=` works, in reality you're creating a *new* array behind the scenes every time, because arrays are by definition *fixed-size* collections.

With larger collections, this can become a performance issue, and it is better to use a *list* data type instead, such as `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
$allcontacts = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[object]
$allcontacts.Add(('one', 'two'))
```

Note the need to enclose the array to add - as a single list element - in `(...)` so that the `.Add()` method recognizes it as a single argument.

---

Taking a step back: **You can let *PowerShell* collect the `$contact` sub-arrays in the overall `$allcontacts` array by simply capturing the output from the entire `foreach` command**:

```
$c = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Contacts_Backup.vcf
$contact=@()

$allcontacts = @(foreach ($line in $c){
    $contact += $line
    if ($line -eq 'END:VCARD'){
        # Output the $contact array as a *single* object,
        # using ",", the array-construction operator
        , $contact
        # Reset for the next contact.
        $contact=@()
    }
})
```

`$allcontacts` will end up as a regular PowerShell array, typed `[object[]]`.
Use of the array-subexpression operator (`@(...)`) is only necessary if you need to ensure that `$allcontacts` is an array even if the `*.vcf` file contains only *one* contact definition.

---

<sup>[1] A non-generic alternative is `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`, but its downside is that its `.Add()` method *returns a value*, requiring you to suppress that value with, e.g., `$null = $arrayList.Add(...)` so as not to pollute PowerShell's output stream.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This should do exactly what you want:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]$allContacts = @()
[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$contact = @()

$filePath  = 'C:\temp\Contacts_Backup.vcf'
$endMarker = 'END:VCARD'

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filePath))
{
        if( $line -eq $endMarker ) {
            $allContacts.Add( $contact.ToArray() )
            $contact.Clear()
        }
        else {
            $contact.Add( $line )
        }
}

# Ready. Show result.

foreach( $vcf in $allContacts ) {

    "Contact: "
    $vcf

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Only issue is the last line (END:VCARD) is not included in the contact because it would never get to the else clause.