# Powershell to output a list of records in a txt file

Tags: powershell, calculated-property

Running the following in powershell

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\temp" -Recurse -Include "*.csv" 

ForEach($BusinessFile in $BusinessFiles)
{
$bfiles = get-content $BusinessFile.fullname | Measure-Object -line
$bRowsinFile = $bfiles.lines -1

write-host  "Business File Name: " $BusinessFile.name 
Write-host "Number of Rows: " $bRowsinFile -ForegroundColor Yellow 
} 

$records =@{
"File Name" = $businessFile.Name
"Number of Rows" = $bRowsinFile
}
} 

$listofFiles = @()
$listofFiles += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $records

$listofFiles | Out-File "c:\test\output.txt"
Invoke-Item "c:\test\output.txt"
```

Powershell based on the write-host command is working properly.
It gives each CSV file name along with # of rows on each file

Output issue:
I only see the first file name in the output.txt file

Output shows:
File name     and              # rows for the first file only

**Goal:** Is it possible for the output.txt to list all file names  with the corresponding # of rows possible

Thanks

Comment: Be aware, that unless you've got possible issues with 8.3 file naming, `Get-Content` with `-filter` will be quicker than using `-include`. Also be careful using `Get-Content`for this task as it will not take into account possible multiline records, counting those as more than one. The most accurate, though probably slowest, method is to use `Import-Csv` with `Measure-Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to mklement0's answer, but I think I'd just add the information to the existing file info you're already getting.

```
$listOfFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Recurse -Filter *.csv | Select-Object *,@{l='Number of Rows';e={(Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -Line).Lines - 1}}
$listOfFiles | Select Name,'Number of Rows' | Export-Csv 'c:\test\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that **you're mistakenly trying to build up the result array (`$listofFiles += ...`) *after* the `foreach` loop instead of *inside it*** - with proper indentation of your source code that problem would have been more obvious.

Additionally, you can greatly streamline the solution.

```
$listOfFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Recurse -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    'File Name' = $_.Name
    'Number of Rows' = (Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -Line).Lines - 1
  }
}
```

The alternative to constructing a `[pscustomobject]` manually inside a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) command is to use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with [*calculated properties*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), as shown in [TheMadTechnician's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034879/45375). That said, given that in the case at hand you'd need *two* calculated properties - one to calculate the number of lines and one to rename the `Name` property to `File Name`, the added verbosity is probably not worth it.

*Caveat*: As [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) notes, if there's a chance that your CSV files contain individual rows that span *multiple lines* (which is rare), use `(Import-Csv $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count` to calculate the `Number of Rows` field, but note that this will be slower.

Note:

- If your CSV files are small enough to fit into memory as a whole (one at a time), you can speed up your command by using `(Get-Content $_.FullName).Count - 1` to calculate the row count.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642878/45375) for why iteratively "extending" arrays with `+=` is ill-advised, and how even `foreach` loops can be used as *expression* whose multiple outputs can directly be collected in an array by assigning to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to `Get-Content` to the variable `$files`, but iterate over a different array.

The `Write-Host` is working for you because it's inside of the loop.

Your append appears to be outside of your loop, and you are invoking a file that you did not build (at least in the provided excerpt).

If you use formatting standards, it is easier to notice things like falling outside of a loop.

And as Compo mentioned, there are some faster methods that can be used to reach the goal you are seeking.

```
$businessFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp\' -Recurse -Filter '*.csv'
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$listOfFiles = @()

foreach ($businessFile in $businessFiles) {
    $file = Import-Csv $BusinessFile.fullname
    $businessNumRows = $file.Count

    Write-Host 'Business File Name: ' $businessFile.name 
    Write-Host 'Number of Rows: ' $businessNumRows -ForegroundColor Yellow  

    $record = @{
        'File Name' = $businessFile.Name
        'Number of Rows' = $businessNumRows
    }
    $recordObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $record
    $listOfFiles.Add($recordObj) > $null
}

$listOfFiles | Export-Csv 'c:\test\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
Invoke-Item 'c:\test\output.csv'
```

Comment: How are you measuring the  # of rows here ? I dont see on this answer

Comment: Ah you're right, I seemed to exclude that bit. You can use the `Count` property on the csv object to get lines. I've added it to the answer.