# Powershell Export-to-CSV of array providing array properties

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

This code:

```
$concerningMachines = @()
foreach($aMachine in $machineRecords.GetEnumerator())
{
    if($aMachine.Value.ReviewScore -gt $averageAboveAverage)
    {
        $machine = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $machine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MachineName -Value $aMachine.Key
        $machine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ManagedBy -Value $aMachine.Value.ManagedBy
        $machine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastLogin -Value $aMachine.Value.LastLogin
        $machine | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ReviewScore -Value ($aMachine.Value.ReviewScore / $averageAboveAverage * 100)
        $concerningMachines += $machine
    }
}

Export-Csv -InputObject $concerningMachines -Path C:\DG\ConcerningMachines.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Produces this .csv file:

> "Count","Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized"
>   "43","43","43","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False"

...Which is the properties of the array, and not the members of the array. Googling the only advice I find seems to either implement a solution that entire ignores Export-Csv, is dealing with strings (which while collections of characters, the solutions aren't applicable) or appear to be doing exactly what I'm already doing but produce a valid CSV file (I can find some links if needed, but they're forum conversations, not explicit guides).

How do you properly export an array of PSObjects into a CSV files, and avoid the above unintended output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use a *pipeline* to provide the input:**

```bash
$concerningMachines| Export-Csv -Path C:\DG\ConcerningMachines.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

When you pass the same input to `-InputObject`, it is indeed the *array as a whole* that is interpreted as a *single* object to export.

This behavior affects *all* cmdlets and is apparently [as designed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3865#issuecomment-304080873):

> InputObject is a single object to be processed. When used in a pipeline, InputObject is bound to each element in the pipeline and processed one at a time. If InputObject was processed as a collection, then each item from the pipeline would also be processed as a collection.

There are cmdlets where this behavior is useful: `Get-Member`, for instance, allows you to use `-InputObject` to inspect the type of a collection *as a whole*, whereas pipeline input inspects *each element* of the collection.

Neither `Export-Csv` nor `ConvertTo-Csv` fall into that category, and even though **[`Get-Help ExportCsv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) currently misleadingly describes the `-InputObject` parameter thus (emphasis added)**:

> Specifies the object*s* to export as CSV strings. **Enter a variable that contains the object*s* or type a command or expression that gets the object*s***. You can *also* pipe objects to Export-CSV.

The **pragmatic conclusion is to *always use the pipeline* (unless you truly want to pass a collection *as a whole*).**

For a **general discussion** of this behavior, see [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242).

Comment: I can't up vote more. Answer is top notch like always. How dare you question the documentation though :)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74758686/1147688)'s a related *magic* pipe solution, starting with a list and doing some additional CSV magic.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best and easiest ways to put data into an easy-to-read format is with a CSV (comma-separated values ) file. The CSV file will have a line of headers to indicate column name and subsequent values for each column. The structured data is required for positioning in the CSV file

```
#looping the concerningMachines details to print in the excel cell
$concerningMachines | foreach { Add-Content -Path $FilePathLocation -Value $_ }
```