# Powershell script to replace only the tab characters in substrings enclosed in double quotes

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I'm working with a tab separated values (tsv) text file. I'm importing it into Excel but for some reason it is also treating tab chars in strings (denoted with double quotes) as delimiters.

A line in the file looks like this:

```
Name  Quote  Random text
Harry  "I like putting    tabs in sentences"  "Here is another tab   "
```

I'm trying to write a powershell script to read the whole text file, find only tab chars enclosed in quotes and replace them with a space character. I know this will be possible but the issue is I'm not an expert in Powershell or regex :D

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to completely replace tabs with spaces, use solution provided by [Vivek Kumar Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51040084/9902555).

However, if you want to keep it as TSV you can import it to variable, replace tabs with space (in values only) and then export:

```
$content = Import-Csv .\file.tsv -Delimiter "`t"
foreach ($line in $content) {
    $line.Name = $line.Name.replace("`t", " ")
    $line.Quote = $line.Quote.replace("`t", " ")
    $line.'Random text' = $line.'Random text'.replace("`t", " ")
}
$content | Export-Csv .\output.tsv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

By the way, this might not be needed as I for me Excel imports data correctly. Maybe some issue with the file/particular line?

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what the character is, I don't think it is tab after all. Could be new line but I've tried removing that too ('`n' right?). Is there a way to strip out all characters like those?

Comment: You can check which character is it using `[int]$variable[0]` (it'll return [ASCII number](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html) of first character in variable `$variable`) and then replace this one instead of tab. For sure there's a way to replace all such characters using this but think first if it's worth the effort to write a script to handle so much possible characters.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Turns out it was 13 (carriage return) - '`r'.

Comment: I had some similar trouble, main difference is file size, impossible to use Import-CSV to a variable. But using your answer along with https://stackoverflow.com/a/6387587/1985023 did magic in my life.

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
(Get-Content \\PathToYourTextFile\TabFile.txt).Replace("`t", " ")
```

**OR**

```
Get-Content \\PathToYourTextFile\TabFile.txt | % {$_ -replace ("`t", " ")}
```

Both will replace the `tabs` in your text file to single spaces.

Comment: Thanks but I think you've misunderstood. I need to keep all the tabs except the ones inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Hex values](https://www.ascii-code.com/) for quotes and horizontal tab in a replace command

```
(gc "\\Path to Your\file") -replace "[\x22][\x09][\x22]"," " | set-content "\\Path to Your\file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Robert Dyjas has a great answer however I want to expand on his answer and make the replacements dynamic and not have to explicitly call out each field.  Instead the version below does two things:

1. First it checks every single field and replaces Double Quotes, Tabs, Carriage Returns and New Lines within Fields and last it Trims.  Note: TABs are replaced with a space whereas all of the other characters found within a field are replaced with a blank.
2. Second it scans every field and checks if it is a valid date.  At this point you can do whatever processing is needed on these date fields however in my version below in order to INSERT my data into a SQL Server database all of my Dates needed to have years greater than 1900 due to SQL Server lowest year being 1753 (I chose 1900).

To accomplish this I am instead using ForEach-Object and piping $content thru.

```
$content = Import-Csv .\file.tsv -Delimiter "`t"
$content |
ForEach-Object {

    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
    {
        if ( ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($property.Value)  ) {
            # Replace Double Quotes, Tabs, Carriage Returns and New Lines within Fields and Trim.  Note: TABs are replaced with a space.
            $property.Value = $property.Value -replace '\"','' -replace "`t",' ' -replace "`r",'' -replace "`n",''
            $property.Value = $property.Value.Trim()
            
            # Scan fields for dates.  If a Date is found make sure the Year is greater than 1900.  If not update the year to 1900
            if ( ( $property.Value -as [datetime] ) -and ( [datetime]$property.Value -lt (Get-Date 1900-01-01) ) ) {
                $property.Value = (Get-Date $property.Value -Year 1900).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
            }
        }
    }
} |
Export-Csv .\output.tsv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```