# Powershell Import-CSV: either reorder columns with no headers or export-CSV with no header

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I have a CSV file with no headers in which I need to add a column between the first and second column. I ultimately want to export the file with no headers to the same file name (hence why I'm using Import-CSV vs Get-Content).

Here is the script which adds the new column to the existing file:

```
(Import-CSV U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\WB_layers-mod.csv) | 
Select-Object *,@{Expression={'FALSE'}} |
Export-Csv U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\WB_layers-mod.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This adds the a new column as a third column. In doing my googling, I could find no way to reorder the columns without having a header row, so I modified the script as follows:

```
(Import-CSV U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\WB_layers-mod.csv -header H1, H2)| 
Select-Object *,@{Name='H3';Expression={'FALSE'}} |
Select-Object -Property H1, H3, H2 |
Export-Csv U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\WB_layers-mod.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This puts the columns in the correct order, but now I want to export the CSV without the header row I added. However, the only suggestions I'm finding are using Get-Content, Convert-to-CSV, and using Skip 1. That won't work for me because I'm only running PS3 and that option is not available until PS5, and I want to save back to the original file name, which you can't do with Get-Content.

I'm probably making this a lot harder than it needs to be, but I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

**Edited to add**:

For clarification, here is an example of the CSV file I am importing:

```
abc,1/1/2012
def,1/2/2012
ghi,1/3/2012
```

I want to add a column between the first and second columns:

```
abc,FALSE,1/1/2012
def,FALSE,1/2/2012
ghi,TRUE,1/3/2012
```

Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: For a more complete and flexible solution in `powershell`, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74758686/1147688) answer, taking a list and doing some additional magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd read Headers H1,H3 and calculate H2 to have them in the proper order directly.

```
(Import-CSV .\sample.csv -header H1, H3)|
  Select-Object H1,@{Name='H2';Expression={'FALSE'}},H3 |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content New.csv
```

Sample output

```
"abc","FALSE","1/1/2012"
"def","FALSE","1/2/2012"
"ghi","FALSE","1/3/2012"
```

Comment: This looks close to what I'm looking for. Would I be able to write this out to the same csv file name as I imported in?

Comment: Yes, as the initial `Import-csv` is enclosed in parentheses it is read in and you can reuse the file name in the same pipe.

Comment: I'm missing something somewhere because even though it is inserting the second column, it is deleting the third column. It is doing something funky in the Select-Object line because if I output the file right after that, the H3 column is gone.