# Using PowerShell to open large csv files and exporting specific columns

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I'm using the command below to get the first 1,000 rows of data:

```
Get-Content -First 1000 'C:\Users\Inspiron\Desktop\base.csv' | Out-File 'C:\Users\Inspiron\Desktop\sample.csv'
```

However, how can I adapt this command to obtain data ranges. For example, to extract the interval between rows 700 through 900.

Another thing, how can I export only a few variables. For example, my database has 120 columns but I want to save only the variables year (1st column), date of birth (4th column) and state of origin (100th column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this. Building [Mathews helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64244036/4749264):

```
$InCsv  = 'C:\Users\Inspiron\Desktop\base.csv'
$OutCsv = 'C:\Users\Inspiron\Desktop\sample.csv'
$Props  = "year","date of birth","state of origin"

$InCsv = Import-Csv $InCsv
$rangeselect = $InCsv[700..900] # You could use variables here too...

$rangeselect | 
Select-Object $Props |
Export-Csv -Path $OutCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

This takes the additional step of selecting the properties you want and re-exporting them to a new CSV file.

Note: It's unlikely, but if you are working with very large files this approach may have memory issues. It reads the entire file into memory upfront, storing it in the `$csv` variable. This could also happen if the system is memory bound, but that's infrequent.

Technically you don't need to assign the `$rangeselect` variable you can use the range operator "`..`" directly on the Import-Csv command like:

```
(Import-Csv $InCsv)[700..900] | 
Select-Object $Props |
Export-Csv -Path $OutCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Here, the `(..)` completes reading all the CSV data first before referencing, so it should work about the same.

---

If you want to build on the initial sample.  Which has the advantage of only reading the first 1000 lines, most likely bypassing any memory constraints:

```
$InCsv  = 'C:\Users\Inspiron\Desktop\base.csv'
$OutCsv = 'C:\Users\Inspiron\Desktop\sample.csv'
$Props  = "year","date of birth","state of origin"
$Skip   = 700
$First  = 200

Get-Content -First 1000 $InCsv | 
ConvertFrom-Csv |
Select-Object -Skip $Skip -First $First -Property $Props |
Export-Csv -Path $OutCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

This is effectively a one-liner with a few convenience variables. It takes advantage of the parameters in `Select-Object`. Note it too only returns the properties you ask for, and so will output a new CSV file with only that data.

---

You can also combine these approaches, again because `Select-Object` allows for `-Skip`, `-First` and also `-Last` parameters for some rudimentary initial filtering.  That might look something like:

```
$InCsv  = 'C:\Users\Inspiron\Desktop\base.csv'
$OutCsv = 'C:\Users\Inspiron\Desktop\sample.csv'
$Props  = "year","date of birth","state of origin"
$Skip   = 699
$First  = 200

Import-CSv $InCsv |
Select-Object -Skip 700 -First 200 -Property $Props |
Export-Csv -Path $OutCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

In this example you may have to play with the boundaries. But, it's still effectively a one-liner and has the potential to get what you're looking for.

Note: `Select-Object` can tell the command on the left side of the pipe to stop sending data.  However, I'm not sure every cmdlet reacts properly, hence performance may vary compared to the `Get-Content` approach.  That may only be important if you're deal with larger files, otherwise I'd go with whatever approach is considered more readable and/or maintainable...

Comment: I think all "answers" do not address one key point here, i.e. LARGE csv file. In my case, I have a csv file of 700MB. Using import-csv seems does not work on my laptop with 16GB memory and i5 CPU (8th generation).

Comment: Memory constraints are mentioned numerous times in the answer.  In particular pipelining is more memory efficient than reading the entire content up-front.  Moreover, `Select-Object` will tend to stop the preceding pipeline when constraint parameters are reached.  Unless your memory constrains are so severe you can't even get to that point, it should work without error. Further still the use of select properties helps to reduce the memory foot print where applicable.

Comment: In case others may encounter the same memory constraint issue, I ended up using [system.io.file].opentext() method to open a file and then handle lines by lines via readline(). This is pretty much quicker and I can handle 7 million rows (about 800MB csv file) in about 5 to 6 min, while using import-csv seems to be stuck for 10+ min (I have to cancel the process). SO has a similar solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386793/how-to-use-powershell-to-reorder-csv-columns/6387587#6387587

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `import-csv` instead of `get-content`

One way you could achieve this would be to use something like:

```
$csv = Import-CSv $csvPATH 
$rangeselect = $csv[700..900]
```

just writing a quick test you should expect a similar result (myself selecting between much smaller ranges) as:

```
test test1 test2
---- ----- -----
8    9     10   
9    10    11   
10   11    12   
11   12    13   
12   13    14   
13   14    15   
14   15    16   
15   16    17   
16   17    18
```

With regard to selecting specific columns, you can also achieve this with the use of `import-csv`. Using the above as an example you could add:

```
$specificcol = $rangeselect.test1
```

You can see the `.test1` is specifically targetting a column and use this to apply to what you are attempting to grab.