# Limits on Import-Csv?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to import a ~2.5 GiB .csv file containing 7+ million records.

```
-----          2021-09-13    06:28     2745868408 thefile.txt
```

After 3+ hours I stopped the following command. Task Manager was reporting memory utilization near 100% and CPU utilization on all cores ~90%.

```
$x = Import-Csv -Path '.\thefile.txt' -Delimiter '|'
```

Are there any known limits for `Import-Csv`? Must `Get-Content|ForEach-Object` be used?

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.1.4
```

Comment: I don't think there's a maximum size other than the amount of memory you have available. `Import-Csv` being a ram-hog is a known issue due to its use of `[pscustomobject]`, and can range from 2-50 times the original file size. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11027

Comment: What are you going to do with the data? Maybe some other tool would be better than conversion into Powershell objects.

Comment: A more performant option is using some `System.IO` classes like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6387587/7411885

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, yes, I could use System.Io. But, I was hoping for `Input-Csv` to take care of the many forms of quoting and encapsulating delimiter characters in data fields.

Comment: The goal is to validate the data with a database table schema. Make sure all fields are there. See that NOT NULL fields contain data. Test that NUMERIC fields only contain valid numbers, Validate maximum string lengths are not exceeded. etc...

Comment: Are you only importing records that are determined to be valid, or do you import all records only upon determining that all are valid? The latter would require enumerating the records twice. Otherwise, what you've described thus far doesn't sound like you ever need more than one record "in-flight" at a time, in which case your bottleneck is going to be realizing a full array of data (i.e. `$x = Import-Csv ...`) before beginning your processing instead of using `foreach` or `ForEach-Object`. Also, can you elaborate on seeing high CPU usage on "all cores"? `Import-CSV` should be single-threaded.

Comment: Try a .Net CSV parser, here's a [big list](https://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2020/12/fastest-net-csv-parsers) of those with benchmarks.

Comment: @lit you can keep `Import-Csv`'s ease-of-use by using its cousin, `ConvertFrom-Csv`, on X number of lines of your CSV at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You might have more luck using it inside a pipeline, instead of assigning the entire output to a variable.

However...

PowerShell, or scripting in general, is meant to make everyday tasks as easy as possible. That's why things like performance or memory consumption have lower priority over other considerations, such as simplicity and usability.

If you're faced with a very high-load and performance-intensive task, more often than not a script tool is not the ideal option anymore.

Native PowerShell is fine for your everyday 1kb csv files, but for this case, you should probably consider a 3rd party library. Of course, you could still use that one inside of PowerShell. It's .Net after all, that's why it's such a great tool imho. Some good .Net Csv parsers were mentioned in the comments.

As has been commented, I don't think there is any hard-coded limitation of the cmdlet. The limit is only your hardware and the simple fact, that the cmdlet wasn't *designed* to handle huge files performantly, but to be easy to use for everyday cases.

Answer (score 1):

Fully agree with @marsze

Just a test you can do :  If you just want to look for specifics  records in the .csv file, you  should avoid to try to load it into memory, but piping it into a filter. I don't use this method  with import-csv, but with get-content and it allow me to find specific reccords in 2Gb log files with correct performances.