# How to consistently re-order CSV columns?

Tags: csv

I want to reformat a CSV (from a Jira export) so that I know what order the columns are in.  The export may be done by several people and the exported column order depends on each person's individual view.

How can I re-order the columns with a consistent ordering?

Comment: You could use `pandas` to read your files with `read_csv()` and reorder your columns.

Comment: For a more complete and flexible solution in `powershell`, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74758686/1147688) answer, taking a list and doing some additional magic.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of command-line utilities made just for dealing with CSVs that can handle this easily.

Assuming the column names you want to re-order are something like (trying to make up some sensible JIRA names):

- Issue ID
- Date Opened
- Date Resolved
- Resolved By

[GoCSV](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#select)'s **select** command:

```sh
gocsv select -c 'Issue ID','Resolved By','Date Opened','Date Closed' <your-csv>
```

It doesn't matter what order the columns/fields come in, they will go out in that order... but they must all be there, or the command will error.

There's also [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvcut.html)'s **csvcut** command, which has an identical syntax:

```sh
csvcut -c 'Issue ID','Resolved By','Date Opened','Date Closed' <your-csv>
```

Comment: Thanks - Sophos seems to think that GoCSV is infected with malware. I didn't compile myself, only downloaded the latest release zip from Github.

Comment: I haven't looked at 100% of the GoCSV code, but I've been over a lot of it, making my own tweaks and adding new commands... I haven't seen any malware, and that doesn't seem like the authors intent. Did Sophos report GoCSV as being one of _Generic ML PUA_, _Generic Reputation PUA_, or _Generic PUA*_? Maybe [check if it's a false positive](https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000037167?language=en_US). It's good software, I live by it.